# How to indicate a value before a specific field

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Below is a subsetted dataset, I was wondering how do I go about for each set of ids, and sorted by earliest to latest date, create a new column that indicates the row before the "LTD" status? The purpose is to identify the diagnosis or row before hitting the "LTD" status for that unique id. Thanks in advance!

Dataset:

```
id <- c(123,123,123,321,321)
diag <- c("injury1", "injury2" , "cancer", "injury5", "cancer")
date <- as.Date(c('2008-11-1','2009-3-25','2010-3-14', '2015-3-14', '2015-4-15'))
status <- (c("STD", "STD", "LTD", "STD", "LTD"))

data <- data.frame(id, diag, date, status)
```

Result (N for no, Y for yes):

```
1   123 injury1 2008-11-01  STD   N
2   123 injury2 2009-03-25  STD   Y
3   123 cancer  2010-03-14  LTD   NA
4   321 injury5 2015-03-14  STD   Y
5   321 cancer  2015-04-15  LTD   NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, the `LTD` row is the last row in the group when sorted by `date`. So, the task is to create a new column based on grouped data using `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(date) %>%
mutate(yes_no =  case_when(row_number() == n()-1 ~ "yes",
                           status == "LTD" ~ NA_character_,
                           TRUE ~ "no")) %>% ungroup()
```

**UPDATE**: When `LTD` is not the last value within the group:

```
data <- data %>% mutate(lead = lead(status)) %>% group_by(id)  %>%
  mutate(yes_no =  case_when(lead == "LTD" ~ "yes",
                             status == "LTD" ~ NA_character_,
                             TRUE ~ "no")) %>% select(-lead) %>% ungroup()
```

Comment: Thanks for the Response! What if LTD isn't the last row in the group? So that it will mark Y for every row above the LTD row?